# Replace Text with jQuery if text exists

Tags: jquery, if-statement

What I am trying to do in jQuery is to take the first comment, out of a group that is all hidden until the user clicks on a button, and output that first comment so it is visible.  I have this working, to a point.  I want it to happen when the page loads, so I have it in the document.ready, but it won't work.  So I attached it to a mousemove event, and it works.

But what I want to do now is if there is a comment, take the comment and show it like I have previously.  But if there isn't a comment, then show the words 'No Comment'.  Below is the code I'm using.

```
if ( jQuery('.dsq-commenter-name').length ){
          jQuery(document).mousemove(function() {
            jQuery('#comments p strong').text( jQuery('.dsq-commenter-name').text() );
            jQuery('#comments p span.comment_excerpt').text( jQuery('.dsq-comment-text').text() );
        });
      }
```

This code isn't working.  If I take away the if statement, it works fine to replace the text, but if no comments at all, it just puts empty space instead of leaving the words 'No Comments'.  If I put the code directly into the console, it works.  So I'm not sure why it won't work when the page loads.  I'm assuming it has to be something with the if statement, but I've tried all kinds of things and can't get it to work.

EDIT:
Not shown in this code but I have everything in a jQuery(document).ready(function() {
and that doesn't seem to help.  But the comments are handled by Disqus, and so I'm thinking they are loaded later, so how would I go about attaching an event to them?

SECOND EDIT:
Okay I've fixed it, not sure if it is the best way to do it though.  Thanks to @Jacob, I decided the comments were loading after the code had already executed.  So I added on to the code using setTimeout, and so the function will run a second or so after the page loads, which works.  Again, not sure if this is the way to do it or not, so please correct me if I'm wrong or if you want to see the code.

Comment: Are the comments present in the DOM when the page is initially loaded?  If not, then you won't be attaching the `mousemove` event (that's what's controlled by the `if` statement).

Comment: Try putting this entire thing in a jQuery onload execution: `jQuery(function(){ /* All code goes here */ });`

Comment: Bear in mind that the mousemove event is not a one time thing, it is called every time the browser detects mouse movement. So a little wiggling of the mouse might easily run your code a couple of hundred times.

Comment: So I think the comments are loaded later, so they probably aren't available in the DOM.  Is there a way to attach an event to them anyway?  And also, I didn't want to use the mousemove event but I couldn't get it to work just on document.ready.  But that is probably because the comments weren't loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure "length" is the best variable to check.  Try val:

```
if (jquery('.dsq-commenter-name').val() != "") {  //or try != null
    //do stuff.
}
```

Comment: `.val()` would only work on user input elements, and as it's a jQuery object, it would never be null, just empty.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('.dsq-commenter-name')` will return the jQuery selector locating the desired element. .length will always be true unless the element does not exist, regardless of content. If you care for text you want to do a .text() on the output. It will return null if no elements were found by the query.

Probably

```
if (jQuery('.dsq-commenter-name').text()) { // checks for "", null, undefined
```

Comment: Well the class I'm checking for only exists if there is a comment.  So I probably could just check and see if there is text, but if there isn't a comment, the class won't exist so I'm pretty sure it will return the right thing.